# ABAP export to memory, obsolete short form using text field literal

Tags: abap

We are writing a tool in Java that parses and transforms ABAP code. We therefore have no intention to write new ABAP code but our tool has to handle all of ABAP, even obsolete statements. Furthermore, I'm not an ABAP expert.

In customer code, I see the following statement variant

```
  export ' ' to memory ID 'AVG_PRC'.
```

The only import in this program (including all includes) with this memory id is

```
  IMPORT AVG_PRC FROM MEMORY ID 'AVG_PRC' .
```

I know the `EXPORT ... TO MEMORY ...` statement with a variable in position of `dobj`. The parser also accepts a character literal here.  But what does that statement do?

I tried to read back the value with `IMPORT` but failed: the parser does not allow text field literals here. On the other hand, the statement is in productive code, so I assume it does something useful.

EDIT:

- changed example, added matching IMPORT statement

Comment: You say: _" ... the statement is in productive code, so I assume some it does something useful."_
Can you show us the import statement of this line? I have never seen EXPORT statements without a parameter list.

Comment: I've changed the example to one where I see an IMPORT statement that should be the matching one. At least, it uses the same memory id.

Comment: I would assume that exporting space is like reseting the memory parameter. And you cannot be absolutely sure where the memory id is set or imported due to the fact that every program in a user session can read or change the value, it must not solely be in your programm (and includes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is guesswork through reverse-engineering and not supported by any official documentation as far as I know.

The ABAP debugger contains a tool to inspect the memory areas.

```
DATA named_variable TYPE c LENGTH 10 VALUE 'Foobar'.
EXPORT named_variable TO MEMORY ID 'ZFOOBAR'.
```

results in

[image: first export result]

```
EXPORT 'Boofar' TO MEMORY ID 'ZFOOBAR'.
```

results in

[image: second export result]

Apparently, the system does just [what the documentation says](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapexport_import_obsolete.htm):

> ...the parameters are saved or found implicitly in the cluster under
>   the name of the specified data object.

Apparently, the only way of retrieving the value again is the dynamic access, which is a bit cumbersome to write:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF t_import_value,
         name   TYPE c LENGTH 30,
         target TYPE c LENGTH 30,
       END OF t_import_value,
       t_import_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t_import_value WITH DEFAULT KEY.

DATA(import_table) = VALUE t_import_table( ( name   = '''Boofar'''
                                             target = 'NAMED_VARIABLE' ) ).

IMPORT (import_table) FROM MEMORY ID 'ZFOOBAR'. " this changes the value of NAMED_VARIABLE!
```

I sincerely wish you the best of luck implementing any transformation for this in your tool...

Comment: Thanks for going through all the lengths to provide an explanation. Most probable, such an EXPORT statement is a programming bug an we will report it as such.